# Issue while sending data to Firestore database in swift

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to send data to firestore database, i have created a request but when i hit a request it get crashed with error message, `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: __SwiftValue'`. I got the point why it is crashing i'm trying to send my structure data in params dictionary, that's why it is getting crash, i want to send array of data that contain playername and player image,This is my code,

```
func saveTeamAPI()
{
    let image = teamImage.image
    let data = image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)

    let getTeamData = TeamData(teamName: self.teamNameTxt.text!, teamImage: "James", playerArray: self.playerArray)

    let dbRef = Firestore.firestore()
    var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
    ref = dbRef.collection("Team").document()
    let docId = ref?.documentID
    print(docId)
    let params : [String : Any] = [

        "teamName": getTeamData.teamName ?? "",
        "teamImage": getTeamData.teamImage ?? "",
        "players": getTeamData.playerArray ?? []
    ]
    ref?.setData(params)
    {
        (error) in

        if let error = error
        {
            print("Error is \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
        }
    }
}
```

That is my Team Data struct,

```
struct TeamData {

var teamName : String?
var teamImage : String?
var playerArray : [PlayerData]?

var dictionary : [String:Any]
{
    return [

        "teamName" : teamName ?? "",
        "teamImage" : teamImage ?? "",
        "players" : playerArray ?? []
    ]
}
```

} 
and thats my playerdata array,

```
struct PlayerData {

var playerName : String?
var playerDetail : String?
var playerImage : [UIImage]?

var dictionary : [String:Any]
{
    return [

        "playerName" : playerName ?? "",
        "playerImage" : playerImage ?? "",
        "playerDetail" : playerDetail ?? ""
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: The error is clear: `UIImage` cannot be saved in the database. You could save the URL and the image separately in a folder or the base64-encoded string of the data representation of the image.

Comment: i have also fix this, first i send all the image to storage and then as all get upload i retrieve them in an array of string and pass that string array to team data struct. @vadian

Comment: Let me clear you what i want to achieve, I have a form in which there is Team name and Team Image and for Players i want to send players array that should contatin player name and player image. How i can send all this data in firestore? @vadian

Comment: I'm not familiar with Firestore, I don't know which kind of image data Firestore supports, anyway **not** `UIImage`.

Comment: i'm just trying to store image also in a string as i get image url in a string form, my issue is just this how i can send my custom struct object for  getTeamData.playerArray in a string form? .@vadian

Comment: You have to map the struct to a dictionary, or – if Firestore accepts JSON – encode the structs with `Codable`

Comment: can you explain how i can map to dictionary, yes Firestore accept data in JSON. @vadian

Comment: Adopt `Codable` and use `JSONEncoder` to encode the structs. Questions about encoding and decoding JSON have been asked a zillion times.